# Sending data between .net applications over the internet

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, messaging

I am sending small messages consisting of xml(about 1-2 KB each) across the internet from a windows application to a asp.net web service.

99% of the time this works fine but sometimes a message will take an inordinate amount of time to arive, 25 - 30 seconds instead of the usual 4 - 5 seconds. This delay also causes the message to arrive out of sequence.

Is there anyway i can solve this issue so that all the messages arrive quickly and in squence or is that not possible to gurantee when using a web service in this manner ?

If its not possible to resolve can i please get recomendations of a low latency messaging framework that can deliver messages in order over the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: the internet is unreliable. there's nothing you can do about it generally (without investing a lot of money). put sequence numbers in your message so that they can be re-ordered at the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway i can solve this issue so that all the messages arrive quickly and in squence or is that not possible to gurantee when using a web service in this manner ?

Using just webservices this is not possible.  You will always run into situations where occasionally something will take much longer that it "should".  This is the nature of network programming and you have to work around it.

I would also recommend using XMPP for something like this.  Have a look at [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org) for info on the standard and [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) for a set of client libraries for .Net.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a little off target, but have you looking into the XMPP (Jabber) protocol.
It's the messaging system that GTalk uses. Quite simple to use. Only downside to it, is that you will need a stateful service to receive and process the messages.

I also agree with @Mat's comment. It was the first solution that came to mind, then i remembered that I used XMPP in the pas to acomplish fast/ small and reliable messages between servers.

http://xmpp.org/about-xmpp/

if you search google you will easily find .net libraries which support this protocol.
and there are plenty of free jabber servers out there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure your messages are sent in sequence and are resolved as a batch together is to make one call to the webservice with all messages that are dependent on each other as a single batch.

Traditionally, when you make a call to a web service you do not expect that other calls to the web service will occur in a specific order.  It sounds like you have an implicit sequence the data needs to arrive in the destination application, which makes me think you need to group your messages together and send them together to ensure that order.

No matter the speed of the messaging framework, you cannot guarantee to prevent a race condition that could send messages out of order, unless you send one message that has your data in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending messages in a sequence across internet, you will never know how long will take the message to arrive from one point to another. One possible solution is to include in each message its position in the sequence, and in each endpoint implement the logic to order the messages prior to processing them. If you receive a message out of sequence, you can wait for the missing message, or request to the other endpoint to resend it.